# Using associativity for elements from different groups

Tags: matrices, vectors, self-learning

My course problem booklet (Mathematics BSc, second-year module in Algebra, unpublished) has a question,

> For any $\textbf{x}, \textbf{y} \in\mathbb{R}^n,$ let $\textbf{x} \cdot \textbf{y} := \textbf{x}^T\textbf{y}$ (ignoring the brackets on the 1-by-1 matrix, so $\textbf{x} \cdot \textbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}$.) Prove that if $A\in O_n$ then $(A\textbf{x})\cdot(A\textbf{y})=\textbf{x}\cdot\textbf{y}$ for all $\textbf{x},\textbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

The solution given in the solutions booklet is
\begin{align}
(A\textbf{x})\cdot(A\textbf{y})
& = (A\textbf{x})^T(A\textbf{y}) && (1) \\
& = (\textbf{x}^TA^T)(A\textbf{y}) && (2) \\
& = \textbf{x}^T(A^TA)\textbf{y} && (3) \\
& = \textbf{x}^TI\textbf{y} && (4) \\
& = \textbf{x}^T\textbf{y} && (5) \\
& = \textbf{x}\cdot\textbf{y}, \text{ as required.} && (6)
\end{align}
The step from line (2) to line (3) uses associativity. But what group is this property taken from? It seems to me that $\textbf{x}^TA^T$ and $A\textbf{y}$ are both in $\mathbb{R}^n$, while $A^TA$ is in $O_n$, so moving the brackets changes the groups to which the terms belong. Why is that OK?

Comment: The product of matrices of various sizes is associative when it is defined. So if $A(BC)$ and $(AB)C$ are defined, they are equal.

Comment: @markvs Is that by inheritance from some group, or for some other reason?

Comment: No group is involved here. This is the associativity property of maps: if $A: S_1\to S_2, B: S_2\to S_3, C:S_3\to S_4$ then $A\circ (B\circ C)=(A\circ B)\circ C$.

Comment: @markvs Think I've got it. Thanks.